# Can air plasma be used as a fuel source in ion propulsion?

Tags: forces, energy, electricity, electric-fields, charge

After doing some calculations (using conservation of energy, $F=qE$, $E_k = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$ etc), I came up with the formula for the exit velocity, $v$, of a mass, $m$, with charge, $q$, being accelerated through a potential difference, $U$, to be

$v = \sqrt{\frac{2qU}{m}}$.

Assuming air is 78% $N_2$ and 22% $O_2$, and each molecule of $N_2$ and $O_2$ gains a single positive charge (e.g. By bombarding the molecules with high energy electrons, or by energizing them with UV or Xray radiation so that they loose an electron) , the charge of 1 gram of air can be calculated,

$q=\frac{0.78}{28}\times6.022\times10^{23}\times e + \frac{0.22}{32}\times6.022\times10^{23}\times e \approx 3346.5 C$

Using the velocity formula where $U=10V$,

$v=\sqrt{\frac{2\times3346.5\times10}{0.001}}\approx8181ms^{-1}$

Thrust, $T$ is given by

$T = \frac{dm}{dt}v$

$\frac{dm}{dt}=0.001kgms^{-1}$ and $v=8181ms^{-1}$, thus $T=0.001\times8181=8.181N$

My question is whether there are any ways in which air could be ionised so as to produce a meaningful amount of thrust force, while also using a realistic amount of energy.

Comment: What do you suppose happens to the negative charges?

Comment: This is the part I need help with ~ how to charge the particles in the most energy efficient way. I edited in some of my initial ideas, but I don't know how scientifically valid they are.

Comment: Plasma is electrically neutral.  E.g., an O2 molecule may have an electron stripoed away, but the electron doesn't go away.  It hangs around, eager to recombine with anything yhat has a positive charge.  An ion thruster needs to squirt out electrons too, or it will quickly build up enough negative charge to just stop the ion beam.

Comment: Perhaps anodes could be introduced around the edge of the ionisation chamber to attract/control the path the electrons take. This would also be beneficial as the electrons could be recycled through a circuit. Would this interfere with the ionisation process?

Comment: You need to get rid of the electrons.  I'd suggest reading up on ion thrusters.

Comment: Also you would do well to read up on energy conservation.  It takes a lot of energy to produce a plasma.  Once you've got a plasma, it's basically an electrically neutral, conductive, fluid.  It's possible to "push" against it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamic_drive) to propel a vehicle, but so far impractical.  Bottom line: the plasma does not provide energy for propulsion; the vehicle must provide energy to produce, maintain, and push against the plasma.